# Pie charts within a list

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, lapply

Let me start off by saying that I know pie charts are terrible methods of accurately displaying data but I have been asked to produce this as part of a report. I have a data set that contains information about location, injury type, and then several fields of personal data. I would like to display a pie chart of the percentage of each type of injury that occurs at each location. I've tried this where facility2 is a list of 52 elements created by splitting the full dataframe by ServiceSite.x. This partially works but the pie charts created only contain the count for one "initial type".

```
    summarized_list <- lapply(facility2, function(x){
  x %>% group_by(InitialType) %>% summarize(length(InitialType))
})
pies <- function(z) {
  ggplot(z, aes(x = "", fill = length(InitialType)))+ 
    geom_bar(width = 1, na.rm = TRUE)+
    coord_polar(theta = "y")
  }
lapply(summarized_list, pies)
```

[image]

This also partially works and would be perfect, but only prints out 13 charts instead of all 52

```
pies2 <- function(x) {
  ggplot(x, aes(x = "", fill = InitialType))+ 
    geom_bar(width = 1, na.rm = TRUE)+
    coord_polar(theta = "y")+
    xlab(x$ServiceSite.x)
}
lapply(facility2, pies2)
```

[image]

and gives this error

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, fill
```

I know the first method splits the data perfectly while providing correct counts, I just can't figure out what I need to change in the ggplot() to have all injury types display for each facility. I would also like to add a label of percentages if possible or at least just the counts.

```
Sample data: 
ServiceSite.x InitialType
2   Dermatitis
2   Diabetic
2   Pressure Injury
2   Pressure Injury
3   Pressure Injury
3   Other
3   Laceration
3   Other
4   Pressure Injury
4   MASD
4   Blister (Non-Pressure)
4   Skin Tear
4   Pressure Injury
5   Skin Tear
5   Other
5   Contusion
5   Skin Tear
5   Surgical(Non-Healing)
5   Pressure Injury
6   Pressure Injury
1   Pressure Injury
6   Pressure Injury
6   MASD
1   Surgical(Non-Healing)
1   Pressure Injury
1   Skin Tear
1   Contusion

facility2 <- split(full, full$ServiceSite.x)
```

both variables are factors.

Comment: Your second approach seems to work fine for the sample data that you give. Have you identified what's different with the facilities whose data throw an error?

Comment: @MikkoMarttila As far as I can tell there is nothing different. The only thing that might change would be that not all facilities will have records of every dingle type of injury, but this doesn't seem to be an issue with the ones that do print.

Comment: Perhaps you could include some of the data that fails? It's not really possible to diagnose this further otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting the error you're showing, so you might want to go through and find the culprit, which may not be in the sample you posted. I'm using `purrr::map` rather than `lapply`; that's partially preference, and partially how well it fits in with a piped workflow. I also find `map` functions easy for debugging, since it will print the name or index of each item as it's being mapped over; this often helps me figure out where in a list a problem is.

The first set of plots here just come from rewriting your code using `purrr::imap`, which maps over two lists: the list itself, and its names. `split` names the list based on the values in `ServiceSite.x`, so you now have access to them to set the `xlab`. I'm not sure if one bug might have been in setting the `xlab` with `x$ServiceSite.x`, which seems like it should have returned an entire vector, not just a single string.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

pies1 <- df %>% 
  split(.$ServiceSite.x) %>%
  imap(function(data, site) {
    ggplot(data, aes(x = "", fill = InitialType)) +
      geom_bar(width = 1) +
      coord_polar(theta = "y") +
      xlab(site)
  })
```

I'm using the `patchwork` library to stick all the plots together just for easier display here.

```r
reduce(pies1, `+`) + plot_layout(ncol = 2, byrow = T)
```

[image]

For the labels, do a little data prep first to calculate counts and percentages. Here I did this with a couple `dplyr` functions. Then add a `geom_text` with `position_stack(vjust = 0.5)` so the texts will 1. stack going around the circle, the same as the bars do, and 2. be centered in the wedges. I'll leave it up to you to format the text as you want, including adding count labels instead or in addition.

```r
pies2 <- df %>%
  split(.$ServiceSite.x) %>%
  imap(function(data, site) {
    data %>%
      count(ServiceSite.x, InitialType) %>%
      mutate(share = round(n / sum(n), digits = 2)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = "", y = n, fill = InitialType)) +
        geom_col(width = 1) +
        geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(share)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
        coord_polar(theta = "y") 
  })

pies2[[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: You can lower your code golf score by replacing the `group_by(ServiceSite.x, InitialType) %>% summarize(count = n())` with just `count(ServiceSite.x, InitialType)`.  You'd have to modify the mutate statment to to refer to `n` as that is what `count` spits out by default.

Comment: @JakeKaupp you're right, I was thinking I'd need to keep the grouping to pass into `mutate` and get the right sums, but in this case there's only one first group in the `group_by` hierarchy, so that doesn't matter

Comment: @camille this worked really well until the edits were made. The only other thing I can't resolve is how to pull the labels to the outside of the chart. I've tried making a new var "breaks" in the mutate statement and using it in scale_y_continuous but no dice

Comment: @regents What edits? And how would you pull the labels outside the chart? Like setting the y-breaks instead of drawing `geom_text`s? Breaks would be pretty awkward, don't you think? They'd be at the border between one wedge and the next.